# Why there exist integer $b,c$ such $a=b+c$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ is prime number,and $p>5,p\equiv 1\pmod 4$,
we Define:an integer $a$ is called a **quadratic residue** modulo $p$.:if there exists an integer $x$ such that:
$$x^2\equiv a\pmod p$$

show that: for every integer $a$,there exist integer $b,c$ such
$$a=b+c$$
and $b,c$ **non-quadratic residues** modulo $p$

Comment: I am confused about the word "new".

Comment: You could use the Cauchy-Davenport theorem: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy-Davenport_theorem", but there's probably a simpler way.

Comment: How to use this theorem ?

Comment: @Aravind: How to use Cauchy-Davenport in this case?

Comment: Well, let $A=B$ be the set of quadratic non-residues. Then Cauchy-Davenport says that $|A+B| \geq 2p-2$, so at least one non-zero square and at least one non-zero non-square can be written as $b+c$. This is enough: if $a=b+c$ where $a$ is a square, then for any other square $A$ we have the representation $A=\dfrac{b}{aA}+\dfrac{c}{aA}$; a similar argument works for non-squares as well.

Comment: The word "New" should be deleted. "Quadratic residue" is standard usage.

Comment: Another property of primes greater than 5 is that any non-0 residue mod p is the sum of two unequal (mod p) non-zero quadratic residues (mod p).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $r$ is such that both $r,r+1$ are not quadratic residues.
Also suppose that $s$ is such that both $s,s+1$ are quadratic residues.

Now if $a$ is a quadratic residue, we can write $a=b+c$ where $b=(r+1)a$ and $c=-ra$; if $a$ is a non-residue, write $a=b+c$, where $b=(s+1)a$ and $c=-sa$.

We used the fact that $-1$ is a square for primes that are $1 \pmod 4$ and that reciprocity is multiplicative.

Also such $r,s$ do exist, because otherwise that would mean the numbers up to $p$ are alternatively residues and non-residues; this cannot happen because there are both even and odd squares, eg: $1$ and $4$.